# calculation of age based on any preveous time

Tags: r, date, datetime, date-formatting, date-conversion

Is there a way to find the solution of problem like this;

if my age on 10/jan/2010 was 2 year how much will be the age on 10/April/2012.

kind regards

Comment: That's fairly simple, but the exact solution depends on your data structure. Do you have a sample you can share using dput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `difftime()` to calculate the difference and then add the age. Something like this:

```
earlier_age <- 2
diff <- as.numeric(difftime(latest_date, earlier_date), units="years") 
#make sure that dates are actually date objects (using as.Date())
new_age <- diff + earlier_age


#So for your example:
latest_date <- as.Date("10/April/2012", format = "%d/%B/%Y")
earlier_date <- as.Date("10/jan/2010", format = "%d/%b/%Y")
earlier_age <- 2

diff <- as.numeric(difftime(latest_date, earlier_date), units="days")/365.25
new_age <- diff + earlier_age
```

You can change the units to weeks, hours and so on as per your requirement

Comment: I get "invalid units specified" for units="years". What am I missing?

Comment: Use other units like weeks or days and then convert.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the dates, for example:

```
x <- as.Date("2010-01-10")
y <- as.Date("2012-04-10")

>y-x
Time difference of 821 days
```

From here, just add that to 2 years. Let me know if this helps!